problem in different datatype when using varchar as foreign key in database mysql xampp phpmyadmin
I have primary key subject in table teachers. I want to use subject as primary foreign key in table marks. Subject is varchar(50). And the attribute I want to apply the foreign to it called mark_teacher_subject is also varchar(50). I chose the attribute to be index. The index then called mqrk_teacher_subject (renamed to mark_teacher_subject) with size 50.
the problem when I want to make the relation and link the attributes mark_teacher_subject from table marks and subject from table teachers I got an error that there is data type problem.
subject from teachers:

mark_teacher_subject index:

relation and error:

The error text:  Error creating foreign key on mark_teacher_subject (check data types)
I tried not to specify the length when choosing the index and didn't work. How to link the too tables through varchar column

Make sure the CHARSET and COLLATION are the same for both columns.

@Barmar what is charset? and i think i didn't change the collations on both so i think they are on the defaults

That error means there's some difference between the columns in the two tables. Use SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename to see each table definition and make sure the two columns have identical definitions. There are many previous questions about this error code.

thank you for the information, I will try it tomorrow ❤
@Barmar Sorry for being late too
